# How to create xml element with no attributes but with value

Tags: java, xml, tags, element

I am looking to create the following:

```
<element="value"/>
```

but can only find examples to create:

```
<element attribute="value"/>
```

could you give me the syntax to create this in Java?

Comment: The XML snippet you want to create is not valid XML. Also, I don't understand your question. What do you mean, create XML in Java?

Answer (score 3):

Is that really valid? Attributes is to add additional data to an element, as key/value whereas its value should be denoted within the opened tag-space, such as:

```
<element>Value</element>
```

as that would be the valid way for any parser to read it.

Comment: In my scenario we originally had a single element with many attributes but we want to separate them out into their own elements, surrounded by a parent element. In reality the value refers to the element name but then everybody element would just have a "name" attribute which seems a bit redundant. I'm not 100% sure how our parser works but that's the format that it will be expecting

Answer (score 0):

@Richard Tyregrim is right, but actually Value represents an inner text here.

```
<element value="_value_"/>
```

This is the example how you can introduce it in another way.

```
     // carname element
     Element element = doc.createElement("element");
     Attr attrType = doc.createAttribute("value");
     attrType.setValue("_value_");
     element.setAttributeNode(attrType);
     element.appendChild(
         //this is your's node's inner text
         doc.createTextNode("__inner_text_of_node")
     );
     parentNode.appendChild(element);
```

And yes, this XML is valid https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_create_document.htm here is the example how to create XML doc in java.

Comment: I had a look at the example but in it each value being set has a corresponding attribute to set it on. Is there a way the setValue() method can be applied directly to the element itself?